# Unknown error (-1000) executing CL_COMMAND_NDRANGE_KERNEL

Tags: c++, opencl, nvidia

I am using opencl and when trying to execute my kernel an exception is thrown:

```
what(): clEnqueueNDRangeKernel 
 err(): -1000
```

The notify function gives:

```
Unknown error executing CL_COMMAND_NDRANGE_KERNEL on GeForce GTX 560 (Device 0).
```

I encountered this error some months ago and posted it along with the solution in the NVidia forums (to find it when searching), but unfortunately the forums are taken down for now and I forgot the solution. So if you know the source of the error (or can somehow get it from the NVidia forums) please post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I remembered the source of the problem:

The kernel that `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` failed on, has buffers as arguments that are shared between OpenCL and OpenGL. I just forgot to `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` some of these buffers.

It is a bit disappointing that the error is not more specific about the problem (like saying: "Accessing an unacquired OpenGL buffer!").

Comment: The error code has the name `CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR`. It's not defined in the `<CL/cl.h>` header, but in `<CL/cl_gl.h>` (and maybe not even there depending on your version...)

Comment: @leemes: I did not know about `cl_gl.h`, thanks for this information. However, I used the notify function, which comes directly from the driver. This error message should contain at least a hint towards the actual error, which it does not (as you can see).

Comment: I totally agree ;) Which library / wrapper do you use? The official OpenCl C++ wrapper?

Comment: @leemes: I am not sure as it has been a while since I setup my system, but I believe, that I downloaded the cl.hpp from http://khronos.org